# MudBlazor - MudAutocomplete, MudSelect etc. don't have dropdown

Tags: mudblazor

In MudBlazor I use several MudAutocomplete, MudSelect etc. and MudSelectExtended (MudExtensions).

All the different components were working fine. Suddenly all of them in different places in the app at the same time no longer have a dropdown to select the values.

When you start typing letters in an autocomplete, no dropdown opens. If you press enter after typing, it finds the matching value and selects it.

I have checked several components, but I can't find the problem. I have no more ideas where the problem could be.

I am completely stumped as to where to locate the problem and am asking here for ideas to solve this problem.

I've checked some of the components. MudBlazor is correclty implemented. The data for the Autocomplete and the Select are correctly loaded from database (when typing the right letters, you get the correct value), only the dropdown is missing.

I've updatet to the newest version of MudBlazor (and MudExtensions).

Comment: Share your code with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

After downgrading to version 6.12 everything works fine and like expected again...

For the downgrade I had to manually change the version of MudBlazor from 6.13.0 to 6.12.0 with this code in the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.12.0" />
```

A downgrade with NuGet-Manager failed. For testing I updated from 6.12 to 6.13 again and the problems where there agian...

I've postet an issue at GitHub (https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8076).